# Help with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Im having a hard time finding regular expressions for the following cases. Please help! I basically need regular expressions to find .NET naming convention errors in code, using Visual Studio.

1. All private variables should start with an underscore. Therefore i need to look for any expression that looks something like this:

   > `Private` **#ONLY ONE WORD HERE#** `As (String|Integer|Boolean)`
2. All ASP.Net Labels should have ID's prefixed with "lbl"

   > `<asp\:Label.*id="`**#ANYTHING OTHER THAN lbl HERE#**

How do you negate a specific word? I tried doing `^(lbl)` and `(^lbl)`... they dont work.

Comment: the abbreviation regex already contains the word expression ;)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

From a comment below I gather you're using the VS regex search box. This has its completely own regex flavor, different from the .NET engine. Try the following:

1.: `Private ~(_)[:a_]+ As (String|Integer|Boolean)`

2.: `<asp\:Label.*id="~(lbl).*`

---

Original answer kept for archival purposes :)

1.: `Private (?!_)\w+ As (String|Integer|Boolean)`

2.: `<asp\:Label.*id="(?!lbl).*`

`\w+` is "one or more alphanumeric characters" which probably should do in your case.

`(?!lbl)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), making sure that `lbl` cannot be matched at the current position.

`^` means "start of line/string" outside of character classes. It only means "negation" inside of character classes like `[^abc]` (= "any character except `a`, `b` or `c`)

Comment: you forgot to force the underscore :)

Comment: @samy: I don't understand what you mean. The underscore is a valid part of a variable name.

Comment: @Tim: "All private variables should start with an underscore"

Comment: 1) Didnt work. I have the following line in my code: 
Private index As Integer

and your expression didnt find it. I already tried the /w+ before. anything else?

2) It didnt work either. I have a label with ID="test" and it didnt find it either.

Comment: @KennyTM: Ah, I see. Thanks. @Ziad: Try no. 1 again now. And please edit your question to provide some actual lines you're trying the regex on.

Comment: Well regarding it from now, I think there is a missunderstanding. Ziad tries to find convention ERRORS. Tim's solution provides the findings of only VALID conventions. So basically you have to match the exact opposite or am I mistaken here?

Comment: For 1), basically the regex expression should find the following line Private index As Integer (because it should be _index, not index). For 2), the regex expression should find <asp:Label ID="test"> (because the id should have "lbl" as prefix..)

Comment: @Ziad: Did you compile the regex using `RegexOptions.CaseInsensitive`? Otherwise `id` won't match `ID`.

Comment: Wow, VS is weird :D but you should still close the label tag or it will simply include the next one as well.

Comment: @samy: I don't think so. Dot doesn't match newlines in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's first version for #1 does work for me:

```
Private \w+ As (Integer|String|Boolean)
```

For the second approach:

```
<asp:Label.*id="(?!lbl).*?">
```

The not closing of the tag should be the reason it didn't match your example properly.

By the way make sure you use the proper modifiers on your expression. At least use 'i'.

Comment: Weird... they'r both not working for me. How are you testing? Im using Visual Studio's global search box with the Use Regular Expressions checkbox checked.

Comment: @Ziad: Now I see your problem: Visual Studio uses its own regex syntax that has nothing to do with the .NET regex syntax.

Comment: hmmm... do you have any idea how it could be done in Visual Studio then?